# Need to click twice to select asp.net dropdownlist item in IE10

Tags: jquery, asp.net, drop-down-menu, internet-explorer-10

My asp.net application is compatible with IE8. Now it has to make compatible with IE10. I have used updated jQuery JavaScript Library to version 1.8.3 as it was using v1.5. In IE10, for dropdownlist I have to click twice to select an item of asp.net dropdownlist. This was not a case in IE8.

Comment: please add dropdown list code

Comment: The problem has been resolved. I have removed focus call that is added using CSS. e.g. select:focus {border : 2px solid}

Answer (score 0):

IE handles the first click for the focus event, and the second to expand the dropdown.  This is a known quirk with IE along with the other 400+ quirks............

I copied this text from

[Why does an ASP.NET DropDownList control requires two clicks to expand in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5965804/why-does-an-asp-net-dropdownlist-control-requires-two-clicks-to-expand-in-intern)

It may helpful for you